# Error while getting data via JSON using Http in angular2

Tags: json, angular

My .ts file has code :

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {Component,View,CORE_DIRECTIVES,} from 'angular2/angular2'
// import {provide} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'renew',
    templateUrl: 'static/components/library/renew/renew.html',
    styleUrls: ['static/app.css'],
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class Renew{
   http;
   constructor( http:Http){ };
}
```

i have one .Json file having data in the form of arrays. i want to get data from json and want to show in the template. but whenever i use http in the constructor it returns error like following:

```
Cannot resolve all parameters for Renew(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.
```

I have tried official angular2 website's plnkr for demo [link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/snj7Nv?p=preview). but this is also not working for me(it seems that plnkr is for the alpha 37).

i am using angular2 44 alpha. and trying to get data in the child component.
am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: You just missed `HTTP_PROVIDERS`. Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dsLTfL?p=preview) working with alpha 45

Comment: yes this is working fine but only with root element. but when i run the same code in the child component it shows error which i have already mentioned in the question. should i have to add some external code to implement same in the child component or something else ?

Comment: I've updated the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dsLTfL?p=preview) and I can't reproduce your issue. Create a new one to reproduce your error.

Comment: @EricMartinez I have found my problem but unable to solve it. actually the problem is in the child components http is not importing properly from angular2/http. whenever i used http:Http in the consturctor it throws an error "Cannot resolve all parameters for ChildApp(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations" slimier error occurs by removing http from your plnkr. i hope you understand whats my problem is ?

Comment: you'll have to set up a plnkr, guessing is difficult. For what I understood to reproduce your error in my plnkr I do have to remove the import of Http which makes no sense at all.

Comment: i have solved my problem myself. i just have to add `@injectable` to add http. btw thanx for help @Eric